# Xcode simulator not working error - could not load inserted library '/usr/lib/libignitor2.dylib' because no suitable image found

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos, swift2

Updated my xcode this evening to 7.2.1 im running on yosemite 10.10.5

i've just started learning swift, and everytime i try to run the simulator it crashes with the error:

```
could not load inserted library '/usr/lib/libignitor2.dylib' because no suitable image found.
```

I have spent the last 4 hours searching online, there seems to be a few similar errors of inserted library missing but nothing that i can see that helps with this error.  The full code can be seen below.

```
    Process:               Simulator [2907]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Simulator.app/Contents/MacOS/Simulator
Identifier:            com.apple.iphonesimulator
Version:               9.2 (643)
Build Info:            Indigo-643000000000000~28
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Simulator [2907]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2016-09-10 03:00:48.102 +0100
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.10.5 (14F1912)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        1ACB9325-E877-4FA4-FEBD-B9450D15E13A


Time Awake Since Boot: 10000 seconds

Crashed Thread:        0

Exception Type:        EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000002, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries
DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/usr/lib/libignitor2.dylib

Dyld Error Message:
  could not load inserted library '/usr/lib/libignitor2.dylib' because no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /usr/lib/libignitor2.dylib: mmap() error 1 at address=0x107DE9000, size=0x00001000 segment=__TEXT in Segment::map() mapping /usr/lib/libignitor2.dylib

Binary Images:
       0x107da0000 -        0x107dccff7  com.apple.iphonesimulator (9.2 - 643) <2A577F90-517C-3363-A980-EEB79D21FEBF> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Simulator.app/Contents/MacOS/Simulator
    0x7fff65635000 -     0x7fff6566b92f  dyld (353.2.4) <708E385E-50C6-32A3-983C-42E97BEE4346> /usr/lib/dyld

Model: MacBookPro12,1, BootROM MBP121.0167.B14, 2 processors, Intel Core i5, 2.7 GHz, 16 GB, SMC 2.28f7
Graphics: Intel Iris Graphics 6100, Intel Iris Graphics 6100, Built-In
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1867 MHz, 0x02FE, 0x4544464232333241314D412D4A442D460000
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1867 MHz, 0x02FE, 0x4544464232333241314D412D4A442D460000
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x133), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.15.166.24.3)
Bluetooth: Version 4.3.6f3 16238, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SM0128G, 121.33 GB
USB Device: Internal Memory Card Reader
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 27.1
```

Any help would be appreciated.  thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try

```
sudo update_dyld_shared_cache -force
```

I'm trying to fix my beta but it appears to be trying to get after an update and this is the solution I"m working with. If it fails you can try

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/217232/trying-to-force-update-dyld-shared-cache-but-having-some-errors

I hope this is helpful

Comment: Thanks mate, i spent around 10 hours on this but in the end i updated to el capitan and upgraded to the latest version of xcode.